# Problems when registering for a Stack Exchange OpenID

Tags: support, stack-overflow, captcha, sign-up

Registering for a Stack Exchange OpenID is a huge pain; it took me 20-30 attempts. I ran into two problems you might want to look into:

First, there's no indication of password policies:

- Password length
- Character repetition
- Mixture of uppercase, lowercase, numerals and, quote, "special characters"

I tried a bunch of passwords before I hit on one that worked.

Second, 50% of the time I can't make out what the CAPTCHA displays, so I kept getting it wrong

Comment: If you'd like, I can make you a *much* worse registration system. Oh, I can picture it now...

Comment: Isn't there an option the play the captcha audibly if you can't read it? I don't see why that's an issue to you.

Comment: There's nothing worse than when sites don't allow some special characters in usernames and passwords.  I think Gravatar is probably the worst as I remember, lowercase letters only.  That's why I never bothered to get a custom gravatar.

Answer (score 3):

That is why you should use OpenId or Google Account or facebook or yahoo. Why would you even want to reenter that information, if you can keep it one place?

Comment: I the Google button. It's so useful!